# Trouble checking if the value in a list is already been changed from the original and shouldn't be changed again

Tags: python

I am making a game where it generates an item and randomly places it in the displayed list. When I run the code, it occasionally places the random item over a cell that already had one random item placed in that cell. How can I fix my code so that it does not allow a cell to be modified if it already had been? I am using a display list and checking list to keep track of the locations of the modified cells.

Here is what I currently have:

```
import os,random
row,col = 10,13

x,y = 0,0

item_grid = [['\033[33m[%d,%d]\033[m' % (j,i) for i in range(row)] for j in range(col)]

item_placed = [['empty' for i in range(row)] for j in range(col)]

iron = [
  ['\033[90m[ ]\033[m','\033[90m[ ]\033[m'],['\033[90m[ ]\033[m','\033[90m[ ]\033[m']
]

test_sphere = [['\033[92m[   ]\033[m' for i in range(2)] for j in range(2)]

g_sphere = [
['\033[92m[T,L]\033[m','\033[92m[T,R]\033[m'],
['\033[92m[B,L]\033[m','\033[32m[B,R]\033[m']
]

def item_placing():
  item_number = random.randint(2,4)
  print(item_number)
  taken = []
  for i in range(item_number):
    placing_hidden_items = True
    
    while placing_hidden_items:
      item = test_sphere#g_sphere # random item to be placed

      count = 0
      a = random.randint(0,row-1)
      b = random.randint(0,col-1)
      
      ba = (b-1,a-1)

      for i in range(len(item)):
        for j in range(len(item)):
          if count == len(item): placing_hidden_items = False
          
          if (b-len(item) >= 0) and (a-len(item) >= 0):
              if item_placed[(b-len(item))+i][(a-len(item)+j)] == 'full ':
                print('error')
                count = 0
                break
    
              elif (item_placed[(b-len(item))+i][(a-len(item)+j)] == 'empty'):
                
                count += 1
          
    taken.append(ba)      
    
    for i in range(len(item)):
      for j in range(len(item)):
        if ba in taken:
          if (item_placed[(b-len(item))+i][(a-len(item))+j] == 'empty'):
        
            item_grid[(b-len(item))+i][(a-len(item))+j] = item[i][j]
            if (item_grid[(b-len(item))+i][(a-len(item))+j] == '\033[33m[ ]\033[m'):
              item_placed[(b-len(item))+i][(a-len(item))+j] = 'empty'
            else:
              item_placed[(b-len(item))+i][(a-len(item))+j] = 'full '

  print(taken)

item_placing()

for i in range(col):
  for j in range(row):
    print(item_grid[i][j], end = ' ')
  print()
for i in range(col):
  for j in range(row):
    print(item_placed[i][j], end = ' ')
  print()
```

Comment: Only place items if the cell is `!= "empty"`?...

Answer (score 0):

How many items do you want to place? You could construct an iterable of all possible positions in the grid and then find n different, but random positions using

```py
import itertools
import random
row = 10
col = 10
N = 5
positions = sorted(itertools.product(range(row), range(col)))
random.sample(positions, N)
```

More info on the itertools module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

More info on the random.sample function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample

Comment: How would I use this to set the value in the location generated?

Comment: @Red_Stone77 you can save the result of the sample in a variable and use those as indexes?